# Better Text to speech in Android

Tags: java, android

The default voice is not suitable for every purpose. Is there a way (some jar or some online API) by which we can have more natural speech.

Ps. my app is for prayers where computerized voice is not good enough and I don't want to ship self-recorded audio with the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use any external JAR.You need to install another suitable text-to-speech engine for your application.(I think **Loquendo** is good option [See here](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-solution/customer-service-solutions/solutions-services/inbound-solutions/loquendo-small-business-bundle/text-to-speech/index.htm))

you can use following steps-

1)Get the APK of TTS engine

2)put it in your asset folder

3)install this APK from asset folder to android device when user install your app for the first time

4)set this TTS engine as your Default TTS engine

5)You are ready to go.

You can do other checks like:

a)if device has already have Loquendo install then no need to re-install it

b)if user does not set Loquendo as default TTS then prompt the user.

c)programmatically change the TTS language as per your need